# javascript elseif case in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi when I have a condition output in frontend is there a possibility to make a `else if ()` statement as well?

current code looks like:

```
    {this.props.contentComponentData.typeOf === 1
      &&
      <ContentComponentChecklistInstances
            checklistItems={this.props.contentComponentData.checklists}
      />
     }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yeah, but you have to use a ternary operator. Or, you write the inverse condition and do your if block. Ternary opeartor would rather be like `condition ? iftrue : iffalse`. A better way to go about this however would be to extract your condition to a variable, and simply render the variable though, not need to pollute the visual tree

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to make if/else expressions:

```
{someCondition === true ? (
    <TrueComponent/>
) : (
    <FalseComponent/>
)}
```

If you want an if/elseif/else, you can combine multiple conditionals together:

```
{someCondition === true ? (
    <IfComponent/>
) : someOtherCondition === true ? (
    <ElseIfComponent/>
) : (
    <ElseComponent/>
)}
```

These things can be difficult to read, so you should consider pulling this code up above your return statement, using normal if's and elses:

```
let component;
if (someCondition === true) {
    component = <IfComponent/>
} else if (someOtherCondition === true) {
    component = <ElseIfComponent/>
} else {
    component = <ElseComponent/>
}

return (
  <div>{component}</div>
);
```

Comment: @Icepickle you're quite right. I've edited in something to that effect :)

Answer (score 4):

```
    {this.props.contentComponentData.typeOf === 1
      &&
      <ContentComponentChecklistInstances
        checklistItems={this.props.contentComponentData.checklists}
      />
     || condition && ifConditionMetExpression
     }
```

But this is a bit hard to read, I suggest you use ternaries instead:

```
    {this.props.contentComponentData.typeOf === 1
      ? <ContentComponentChecklistInstances
        checklistItems={this.props.contentComponentData.checklists}
        />
      : condition
        ? ifConditionMetExpression
        : null
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 (first condition)
 ? // if first condition true this part run
 : (second condition)
    ? // if second condition true this part run
    : // else part
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Isn't this just what the top answer is doing?