# React render various components based on three logic paths

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am really struggling to get my head around how to render specific components based on logical markers when there are more than two. Usually I'd write something like

```js
render() {
    return (
        isBlue ? <Blue /> : <Red />
    );
}
```

But it gets a lot more complex when I can't use a ternary.

What would be the best way to write a `render` function when I have more than one option?

E.g

```js
const colour = myData.colour;

render() {
    return (
        <Blue />
        /* or */
        <Green />
        /* or */
        <Red />
    );
}
```

How would you handle choosing which React component to render based on the result of `myData.colour` or some other set check?

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/46665567/11187813?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript elseif case in JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46665510/javascript-elseif-case-in-jsx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your questions is about more than 2 and not just 3 components then this is a great place to use a map like so. No switch, no if's and it's performant.

```js
let colorComponents = {
    'blue': <Blue />
    'green': <Green />
    'red': <Red/>
    'yellow': <Yellow />
}

render() { // Can pass null or what ever fallback component you prefer
    return colorComponents[myData.colour] || null;
}
```

Comment: i like that :D awesome

Comment: Thanks. Loads of great solutions posted but this is the cleanest IMO.

Comment: @user1486133 most welcome, also if your colors are known constants you can always define the map key dynamically `let comp = { [color.Blue]: <Blue /> }` that will prevent any human errors when naming strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the checks to inside the render but before the return. So you can do something like this:

```
const colour = myData.colour;
let content;

if (isBlue) {
   content = <Blue />
} else if (isRed) {
   content = <Red />
} else {
   content = <Green />
}

return <div>{content}</div>
```

You can also refactor this to a switch based on `colour`.

Answer (score 0):

do chaining like this

```js
let isBlue = 'blue';

console.log( isBlue == 'red' ? 'red': isBlue == 'blue' ? 'blue' : isBlue == 'green' ? 'green' : 'none'  )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like that based on two condition

```js
const colour = myData.colour;

 render() {
    return isBlue ? <Blue /> : isGreen ? <Green /> : <Red />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

const colour = myData.colour;

```
render() {
    return (
       {colour.Blue?  <Blue />}
        /* or */
       {colour.Green? <Green />}
        /* or */
       {colour.Red? <Red /> }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can export your logic to a function if the options are many and also use the `switch` statement if you dont like the `if-else`.

```
  const renderComponent = color => {
    switch(color) {
      case 'red':
        return <Red />
      case 'blue':
        return <Blue />
      case 'green':
        return <Green />
      default:
        return null
    }
  }
```

and then in your `render` function

```
{renderComponent('blue')}
```