# Natigate to different screes within same page in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have made a main screen in which I have added three button in the header, on pressing I want to open three different screens respectively but its not working.
Here's what I've tried:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      initialstate: 0, //Setting initial state for screens
    };
  }
 render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => this.setState({ initialstate: 0})}>
      <Image source={require('../../assets/add.png')}
            resizeMode="contain"/>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => this.setState({ cardstate: 1})}>
      <Image source={require('../../assets/request.png')}
            resizeMode="contain"/>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => this.setState({ cardstate: 2})}>
      <Image source={require('../../assets/send.png')}
            resizeMode="contain"/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
 
      {this.state.initialstate == 0 ? ( <RequestComp/> ) : ( <TopUpComp/> )  } //Over Here when I use the Third Screen like " : <SendComp/> " it gives me JXS error says "EXPECTED }"
      </View>
```

Comment: You can try tab navigation for this. you find example on this <https://aboutreact.com/react-native-tab/>

Comment: I am familiar with TabNavigator but I wanna do something as above, can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you have an `initialState` state variable that is only updated by the first buttons and the other two are setting `cardState` so even if the ternary statement was formatted correctly it wouldn't have worked either way

But aside from this problem I don't recommend using a ternary for what you're trying to do, because the conditions become difficult to read.

There are multiple ways of doing this, but I like the approach of the accepted answer here [React render various components based on three logic paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63176228/react-render-various-components-based-on-three-logic-paths/63176373#63176373)). The idea is to create an object that holds a mapping of strings to components. Then you can conditionally render an item based on the current key value.

Here's an example of how you could refactor your code to use this approach:

```
const tabComponents = {
  request: <RequestComp />,
  topUp: <TopUpComp />,
  send: <SendComp />,
};

class CustomTabs extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cardstate: 'request', // Setting initial state for screens
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => this.setState({ cardstate: 'request' })}>
          // Button content...
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ cardstate: 'topUp' })}>
          // Button content...
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => this.setState({ cardstate: 'send' })}>
          // Button content...
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {tabComponents[this.state.cardstate]}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay I got the idea but the "tabComponents" u have initialize isn't working onPress.